# CollectionView don't displaying data from List

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I want to display in my app data from Database. I get the data to my view model to list property. I checked whit debugger and it get correct to my List data but after i click Continue nothing display in my list position. Another Bindnig work properly.

Model code

```
 public class Request
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsFinished { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  
}
```

View code

```
<CollectionView x:Name="RequestList" ItemsSource="{Binding Requests}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsListVisible}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

ViewModel code

```
    public List<Request> Requests { get; private set; }

    public string Today { get => DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(); }

    public string NavTitle { get => $"You have { itemNumber} task to do"; }

    public Command AddCommand { get; }

    public bool IsListVisible
    {
        get => itemNumber != 0;
    }

    public bool IsLabelVisible { get =>  !IsListVisible; }

    int itemNumber;

    public async void GetRequest()
    {
        Requests = await App.Database.GetRequestAsync();
        itemNumber = Requests.Count;
    }
```

In Requests property in get i see null ,but before in set was 4 records in list:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFc4C.png

Comment: Are you setting the `BindingContext` properly?

Comment: is GetRequest() is fired after binding has occurred then it will not update unless you use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yes i set BindingContex properly. @Jason I run GetRequest in OnAppearing void and it run properly because it reach breakpoint when i put them into this method and in breakpoint Request have correct value.

Comment: that is irrelevant.  At that point Binding has already happened, and unless you use INPC then your UI will not be notified that the data has changed.  You can easily test this by manually setting the ItemsSource after the data request completes

Comment: Did you try to set BindingContext after you GetRequest in OnAppearing ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not raising the PropertyChanged event on the `Requests` property.

Your ViewModel needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Most MVVM libraries will have a method such as `RaisePropertyChanged`, `FirePropertyChanged` or `NotifyPropertyChanged` which you can use to trigger the event.

This usually looks like:

```
private List<Request> _requests;
public List<Request> Requests
{
    get => _requests;
    set
    {
        _requests = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Until this event is triggered, the UI is not notified of the change of the property.

Alternatively you could make `Results` a [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1), and never overwrite the instance, but simply add and remove items from it. Something like:

```
public ObservableCollection<Request> Requests { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Request>();
```

Then after you fetch your requests:

```
var requests = await App.Database.GetRequestsAsync();
foreach(var request in requests)
    Requests.Add(request);
```

Since `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` and properly fires those events, it will notify the UI when items change in the collection.

Comment: I added this to my code and it not work. It look like i correct get requests to my list and next when the set code end it change List to null. I do some change in my xaml code and the get code in List Request property return null. Maybe i shouldn't call the GetRequests in OnAppearing method?